# Make the div responsive using media queries

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a responsive web and I'm having trouble to do the media queries. I want a specific div to go on the bottom of some div. I'm new to CSS. Can someone help me about this?

I want the **"Upcoming events"** and the **"Content"** of it  to go to the bottom of **"Latest news"** Div. The upcoming events and the content of it are different divs. Within `(min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1260px)`.

[image]

Here's the original css code of the 2 divs that I want to put in the bottom.

```
// this is the title div. The "Upcoming Events"
.title2{
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-left: -7px;
  width: 270px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  display:block;

}
//here's the content
.sidebar{
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;  
  padding:19px;
  width: 270px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  display:block;
  max-height: 374px;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}


 //news div
    .leftbar{
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  padding:19px;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  display:block;
  max-height:741px; 
  overflow-y:scroll;
  margin-left: 20px; 

}
//latest news title div
 .title{
  background:none repeat scroll 0 0 #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 19px;
  padding-left: 19px;
  padding-right: 19px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  width: 250px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #ccc;
  display:block;
   margin-left: 20px; 

}
```

my media queries

```
@media(min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1260px){
   .img-responsive{
    width: 260px;
    height:70px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-right > li > a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right:6px;
 }
    .leftbar{


}
.title{


}
.title2{


}
.sidebar{

}
}
```

Comment: Put it on jsfiddle.

Comment: I don't have jsfiddle..

Comment: Can i put it your jsfiddle?

Comment: Whaaaaaaaaaaat? Where should I get your html markup? You must provide it also. Why don't you open https://jsfiddle.net/ No one will answer for you.

Comment: Just go to https://jsfiddle.net/ and paste your code.

Comment: go to http://jsfiddle.net and enter your html and css code there in the respective frames

Comment: Even don't have account? Wait.

Comment: You don't need an account.

Comment: But my code is so long...

Comment: Come on fellow Filipino. Do it without reason. We'll help you.

Comment: How can i put a bootstrap in jsfiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122251/discussion-between-herm-luna-and-nethken).

Comment: @nethken try my answer before your jsfiddle trail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the width of the latest news container as 100%

```
@media (min-width: 1025px) and (max-width: 1260px)
{
    .title2, .sidebar{
       width : 100% !important;
       max-width : 100% !important;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is css applied at your media query? check the updated answer

Comment: Yeah from the start i put it in my media query.

Comment: can you add latestnews div  css styles in your question and try updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are good but time-consuming and it can really mess you up. Instead of the media query go for bootstrap. It's clean and simple to use, all you gotta do is add the class name and bootstrap will do everything for you. For reference check this [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)